Question about using "now" with past tense in narrative
So question: I wrote something, and I'm being told its incorrect by someone else. The problem is that I'm not sure why. Hoping I could get an answer...
So its a narrative in the past tense. The sentence is as follows (with some changes in content to make sure this remains anonymous):

He was once a great philosopher, but he now spent his days teaching ungrateful students in a local high school.

So I am being told that the "now" doesn't work here. The reason is because now means the current time and must be used with the present tense (the rest of the story, like here, is all in past tense). Thus this sentence is just flat out unreadable.
But I looked on-line for examples... and I found quite a few. For example, a story in The Washington Post:

He was once a star break-dancer in his neighborhood and now spent his days — when he wasn’t protesting — playing video games.

Michelle Obama's memoir:

But I also knew that he now spent his days surrounded by expert advisers.

From what I understand, the "now" in these places means at that time in the narrative, to distinguish it from past events in the same narrative. The usage then should be correct.
Please let me know if I am mistaken. I would really like to better understand what I am missing and where my problem lies.

Related and probable duplicate about using now and the past tense.

Does the dictionary answer this? Google Dictionary lists one sense of now as "(in a narrative or account of past events) at the time spoken of or referred to."
